# EasyMotion without keyboard layout switches for non english text?

Tags: keyboard-layout

My text often contains two languages: english and russian. The problem appears with [EasyMotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) plugin. Assume I have such text:

```
Русский текст и еще текст.
```

and want to find `те`.

[image: sample]

What I do:

1. Starting in normal mode with english layout I do `easymotion-overwin-f2`.
2. Switch to russian.
3. Type `те`. All occurrences are highlighted with english marks.
4. Switch back again to english and select the mark to jump.

In short it looks like: `s<Switch>те<Switch>a`. Where `s` is mapping for EasyMotion action, `<Switch>` is keyboard layout switching, `a` is mark to jump (red `A`).

The problem here are these annoying switchings. The search with standard `/` can be done much easier because of this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29735473/898116). It saves keyboard layout for search and input modes, while normal mode will always be english (it is really important, nothing works correctly in non-english layout for normal mode). Of course, I can try to `let g:EasyMotion_keys` to some russian chars, but I still must switch back after jump.

So my question - what can be done to remove these language switches?